# Bounce email and email limit handle in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, webservices

I have a list of emails. There is a wrong email address in it. i want to send email message to other address by avoiding wrong address in the list. so how can i do? 
**problem:** when i did that all emails bounced due to a single wrong address.

Comment: What code have you written to do the send? How have you come to the conclusion that all the emails fail, not just the one with the bad address? If you post your code and explain the results you're observing then people might be able to help better.

Comment: Hi VT, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particuarly code you're using, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful.